# How can I get a single random number from multiple possible ranges?

Tags: c#, random

I would like to be able to generate a (pseudo)random number from *n* possible ranges, where a range is `x, y` and `x < y`. For example, executing this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write(Random.NextRanges(new Range(1, 6), new Range(10, 16), new Range(20, 31)) + " ");
}
```

will produce something like:

```
3 12 5 22 1 27 29 5 10 24
```

The signature of the method `NextRanges` is:

```
public static int NextRanges(params Range[] ranges)
```

And `Range` is defined as:

```
public struct Range
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Range(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x >= y) throw new ArgumentException("x must be less than y.");
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not sure on is how to implement `NextRanges`, what the most efficient way or the most random way is (I know random can be tricky sometimes). Would you choose a random `Range` and then use `Random.Next()` on that? Or would you keep choosing random numbers until you got one that was within each of the ranges?

Is it also possible to weight the ranges so that a range of 0-100 has far more weight than a range of 100-102, for example?

Comment: Using a composition of random numbers you can easily have one subset of a range have greater probability. Simple example, assume `x` is random: `if x % 2 == 0, range is from 1 to 100, else range is from 1 to 102.`

Comment: `Would you choose a random Range and then use Random.Next() on that?` Yes. You just have to generate 2 random values, easypeasy. If you want to increase the weight of a range, just generate a number between 0-100 and see if it's between 0 and 40 if you want to use 40% for one particular range.

Comment: How can your loop from 0 to 5 print 10 values, what `NextRanges` returns `int`?

Comment: When you say you want the ranges to be weighted, do you simply mean that, e.g. with the ranges (2,3) and (9,100) that each number is equally likely to turn up, or that you actually want to be able to assign explicit weights to each range, e.g. maybe 2 would be selected 20% of the time in my example?

Comment: @TimS. Weighted in proportion to the size, implicitly.

Comment: For a solution to the general problem see http://ericlippert.com/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Would you choose a random Range and then use Random.Next() on that?

No, because that would give numbers in shorter ranges more weight. For example, if one range contains a single number `42` and the other range contains 10,000 numbers, then `42` would be generated roughly 50% of the time.

> Or would you keep choosing random numbers until you got one that was within each of the ranges?

No, because that would not be the too efficient. For example, if the first range is `[1..3]` and the second range is `[200,000..200,001]`, getting a number in one of these ranges would take a while.

I would implement a `Size` property on the range, compute the total size, generate an `int` in the range `index = [0..TotalSize-1]`, and then picked the item at the index as if all numbers in your ranges were numbered sequentially.

For example, in your ranges `TotalSize` would be 6+7+12=25. First, I would generate a random number in the range `[0..24]`, say, 15.  I would then see that `15` falls in the third range, so I'd return `21`.

This would give each range a weight proportional to its size. If you would like to assign specific weights to your ranges, the algorithm would be different: you would compute an equivalent of `TotalRange` by multiplying the actual size by the weight of the range, and totaling up the products. You would then generate a number in the range of that weighted sum, pick the range by working backward from that random number, and then dividing out the weight of the specific range to obtain the position of the random item in the range.

Comment: I think it's important to distinguish between what exactly is supposed to be random: the range and the value inside the range or just the value inside the range. Your solution explicitly states that you will assume only the values inside the range should be random. If he wants the ranges themselves to be randomly chosen then your first remark is incorrect (it's unclear whether or not this is his intention). I believe that's also where his weight for a range comes into play.

Comment: I only wanted the range to be randomly chosen with respect to the resulting number (e.g. what the answer says about 42 vs. 10,000 other numbers is correct, that 42 should show up 1 in 10,000 times not 1 in 2 times).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You are 100% right, that's a fair observation. I added an explanation on the way the solution I describe assigns weights to the ranges, and suggested a way to change these weights.

Comment: Very solid answer then, thanks for the clarification!